# Bulk Import Json into Parse.com backend via rest api, almost there

Tags: ios, json, rest, curl, parse-platform

Evening all,

I just have a quick questions about bulk importing via the rest api. I've tried various methods to automate looping through a file and adding the results to Parse backend without success. One example:

curl -X POST \ -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: Removed" \ -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: Removed" \ -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ --data '{

```
"requests": [
  {
    "method": "POST",
    "path": "/1/classes/testnew",
    "body": {
      @Posts.json
    }
  }
]
```

}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/batch

I've tried many other Curl commands and also checking the network tab in parse when uploading a .json file, it looks like when you click the upload it is using the form multipart command to upload the data in a .json file. Does anyone know of a way to automate uploading of data from a .json file into parse without having to manually execute the batch/individual calls as described in the rest api documentation via cUrl?

Any help would be seriously appreciated :-).

Thanks,

Gerard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems parse doesn't provide desired function . you can still write a small python script quick fix.

```
{
  "all_players": [
          {
              "score": 1337,
              "playerName": "Sean Plott"
          },
          {
              "score": 1338,
              "playerName": "ZeroCool"
          }]
}
import urllib2
import json
import pprint
def frame_request():
  f=open('hello.json','r')
  data = json.load(f) 
  flag=1;
  req = '{ "requests": ['
  for d in data["all_players"]:
    if flag:
      flag=0
    else:
      req=req+','
    req=req + '{ "method": "POST", "path": "/1/classes/GameScore", "body":' + json.dumps(d) + ' }'
  req=req+']}'
  return req
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `-k` or `--insecure` command with curl to handle your `https` link.

Linux supports single quote for data value, but windows doesn't. If you are from windows based OS, then `--data` should be something like below:

```
--data "{sample:\"json-data\"}"
```